# db4o: Query on abstract class type: no results

Tags: c#, linq, db4o

I stored a bunch of objects of various classes that inherited from the abstract class `Creative`.  I wanted to see what was stored so I wrote a method like so:

```
    public void GetCreativeTypes()
    {
        var types = from Creative c in original.AsQueryable<Creative>()
                    select string.Format("{0}: {1}", c.CreativeType, c.GetType());

        foreach (var type in types.Distinct())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(type);
        }

        return;
    }
```

...but this returns no results.  I have also tried:

```
    public void GetCreativeTypes()
    {
        var types = from Creative c in original
                    select string.Format("{0}: {1}", c.CreativeType, c.GetType());

        foreach (var type in types.Distinct())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(type);
        }

        return;
    }
```

with the same results.  How can I get the results I want?

Objects in original collection would be like

```
public class ImageCreative : Creative{}
public class FlashCreative : Creative{}
```

...etc.

Comment: Can you give a sample of what the object that is in original collection

Comment: added a couple of examples; I think that's what you're asking for.

Comment: What is the type for the variable `original`?  Is it `List<Creative>`?

Comment: it was an `IObjectContainer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be unrelated to the query.  The documentation stated that the records did not  need to be committed (just close the container), but once I committed them they were queryable.  That was a headscratcher for me.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is something else going on here instead of your queries, like `Debug.WriteLine` (try `Console.WriteLine` and even `Trace.WriteLine`) is not outputting to your Output window or your collection is being recreated or something wrong with adding to your collection in the first place, etc.

As for your queries, it looks like your using Linq-to-Objects so this query should be fine, and you don't need to specify the type:

```
var types = from c in original 
            select string.Format("{0}: {1}", c.CreativeType, c.GetType());
```

No need for `AsQueryable()` since you don't need to work with Expressions or remote data sources.

It would be also good to see if you get a result when you do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Count: {0}", original.Count ()));
```

Finally, you'll probably have a need to access just a certain derived type from your collection, so here's a little tip on doing that:

```
// returns only the objects in the collection that are type ImageCreative
var onlyImage = from c in original.OfType<ImageCreative>()
            select c;
```

Likewise to get only the FlashCreative you would do this:

```
// returns only the objects in the collection that are type FlashCreative
var onlyFlash = from c in original.OfType<FlashCreative>()
            select c;
```